# Elastic search N-gram not returning expected result

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Trying to figure out the scoring of this trivial example. I would expect to get the document of `brenda eaton` yet I am getting `brenda fassie` as the best result.

```
PUT ngram
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 3,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
   "mappings": {
    "tweet" : {
      "properties" : {
        "text" : {
          "type" :    "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT ngram/tweet/1
{
 "text":"searched the blue sky during the summer"
}
PUT ngram/tweet/2
{
 "text":"sdssded the trans hex during the sssss"
}

PUT ngram/tweet/3
{
 "text":"searched the brenda eaton during the summer"
}
PUT ngram/tweet/4
{
 "text":"sdssded the brenda fassie during the sssss"
}


GET ngram/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "text" : {
                "query" : "brenda eaton",
                "max_expansions" : 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the initial stage of filling the index the relevance of documents may quite strongly depend on their distribution accross the shards. Try to create index with one primary shard and one replica shard and you will get the desired result.

You can find a good explanation of this phenomenon in the following article from Elasticsearch guide: [Relevance is broken!](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-is-broken.html)

Comment: That's insane, good to know. tell me what the reason why I would get the wrong result again if I search for "brenda e" taking into account that I updated my index with one primary and one replica

Comment: @R4nc1d This time nothing special. Slight difference between scores is caused by the field length (the shorter field will get the more score).